# pyOCD - multiple probes, how to connect to the right one?

Tags: stm32, openocd

I have two STM32 boards with own onboard STLINK V2 probes.

```
pyocd list
  #   Probe                           Unique ID
----------------------------------------------------------------
  0   DISCO-F769NI [stm32f769nihx]    066EFF575251717867124843  
  1   NUCLEO-F303K8 [stm32f303k8tx]   0666FF303032424257021242
```

How to select the second board launching pyocd gdbserver?
I have tried using both `--board` and `--target` params specifying `stm32f303k8tx` and `0666FF303032424257021242` but pyOCD still tries to connect to the first board - and fails.
Please advise.
How to achieve the same with openOCD?

Answer (score 0):

pyOCD `--uid` argument needs to be used for that purpose - both for gdbserver and flashing.